# Cross-platform package a node.js app

Tags: node.js, qt, package, distribution

So I have a Node.js app that runs on the command line.

I created a very simple GUI window in Qt which calls the Node.js command line program.

I can package up the Qt GUI with Qt Installer Framework.

It works great.

---

But it only works on my machine...

I need to:

- install node.js on the user's computer. I don't want to rely on the "system" version of node.js and would prefer to have a "sandboxed" version of node.js somewhere in my application's directory. Also, user may not have any compilers installed...
- run `npm` and install a couple of packages to the user's computer
- needs to run on Mac/Windows/Linux

Am I being unrealistic here?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?